# Android HttpPost does not work

Tags: php, android, json, get

I'm attempting to create an application which send data to a remote db using WAMP server. The problem I'm facing is no one appears: no data are sent and no logcat errors are shown, also I can't insert a Toast to see if the application goes into specific parts of code because Eclipse shows it as an errore in runtime mode.

So, here you are the .java code:

```
public class AggiungiProdotto extends Activity 
{
    private static String indirizzo ="http://10.0.2.2/tesina/Aggiungi_Ordinazione";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aggiungi_prodotto);
    new AggiungoOrdinazione().execute();

}

private class AggiungoOrdinazione extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jsonResult = null;
        TextView tv;

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String Nome = new String();

        String Tavolo = intent.getStringExtra("Tavolo");
        Nome = "ciao";

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(indirizzo);  

        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeOutConnection = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeOutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        List<NameValuePair> Comanda = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        Comanda.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Nome", Nome ));
        Comanda.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tavolo", Tavolo));


        try 
        {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Comanda));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);



        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return null;
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute()
{

}
```

}

Then here you are the .PHP code related to the insert data into the db:

```
<?php


// Dichiaro una array nel quale inserirò la risposta in JSON
$response = array();

/* La funzione isset controlla se all'interno della variabile esiste un dato diverso da null.
$_POST è una funzione che inserisce i dati passati attraverso un metodo POST alla variabile seguente. */

if (isset($_POST['Nome']) && isset($_POST['Tavolo'])) 
{

    $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
    $Tavolo = $_POST['Tavolo'];

    // Includo la classe per la connessione al database
    require_once __DIR__ . '/connessione_db.php';

    // Da file incluso posso istanziare un oggetto della clase
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // Query in mySQL Per creare una riga i cui campi hanno i valori passati dall'applicazione.
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pizze(Nome, Tavolo) VALUES('$Nome', '$Tavolo')");

    // Controllo se la riga è stata inserita oppure no.
    if ($result) 
    {

        $response["Stato"] = 1;
        $response["Messaggio"] = "Dati inseriti!";

       // echo in PHP che mi converte il risultato in JSON e la mette nella variabile response.
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else 
    {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Dati non inseriti!";

        // Converto anche qui.
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else 
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Campo richiesto mancante!";

    // Converto.
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Can you help me what is wrong? Is the way im doing correct or am I missing something? 
Thank you.

Comment: LogCat says no errors.

Comment: have u added internet permission in manifest file??

Comment: Yes, "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>" .

Comment: I think you need to do put your http code in an asyncTask, but is weird that the logCat says no error...

Comment: I'm not laying it says nothing. So you say to put an AsyncTask with a String doInBackground and there insert that istructions?
Like this maybe? http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby this chunk of code can help.

**Get**

```
InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonResult = null;

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);    
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeOutConnection = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeOutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);



    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));     

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
```

**Post**

```
        InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonResult = null;

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);  
    //httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    //httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    int timeOutConnection = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeOutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);


    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));   

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
```

**update**

try wrapping your code in this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }).start();
```

but i higly recommend to learn to use the Asynctask, it makes it a lot easier and more stable.
the are lots of good examples on the net of how to use them

use this code for reference and modify it on your needs.
I am sure that this works cause we use this peace of code all the time.

**Edit**

Below I wrote a very simple activity with a subclass of Asynctask

```
public class AsyncTaskExample extends Activity {

private String url;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    url = "http://google.com";

    new WebCall().execute();
}

class WebCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jsonResult = null;

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        //httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        //httppost.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        int timeOutConnection = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeOutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        jsonResult = new JSONObject(result);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        // this method gets called when doInBackground is ready with processing.

        // onPostExecute is also returend on the UIThread. and doInbackground is not.
        // so you cant setText or something else what involves UI components in the doInbackground.
    }
}
```

}

its up to you to do the rest ;)

Hope it helps,

Kind regards

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, but I have some questions:
- Can I implement these example without AsyncTask or they are needed?
- Like I see, I just need to insert my url and my ArrayList which you called params, right?

Comment: no you have to do this threaded / asynctask based. or else you get an networkOnMainThreadException or something like that

Comment: So its correct like i did in the example, right? Thank you for the patience.

Comment: try wrapping your code between this: new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            }).start();

Comment: Saw it, so use Get / Post examples into you Thread example modifying on my needs, right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes indeed, but if you are doing much with network calls then I suggest reading some info on the AsyncTask class. here to give you a litle speed up in the right direction http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Ok I will implement your suggests, then I'll mark you as answered. Thank you a lot, really.

Comment: No problem glad I could help ;) if you got any other questions related to this problem. just leave a comment.

Comment: I'm trying to use AsyncTasks with your helps :)

Comment: Added an example, but dont be afraid if google ;) you can find very usefull tutorials out there

Comment: Ok I've did like you exaplained, do you think is that correct (I've edited the code in my question so you can see it)? By the way it still doesn't do nothing, but if you say that is correct I guess the problem is on the PHP code.

Comment: it looks goood, try to log the json result object.

Comment: Ok today or tomorrow I'll notice you! Don't stop following this problem please :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code

```
List<NameValuePair> Parametri = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
```

instant of

```
List<NameValuePair> Parametri = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

Thanks

Comment: 2 references the maxium size of my List or how many items can it has for each index?